# Realm Swift - How to combine / union queries from multiple models?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I want to query data from multiple models and group it and order it.
How do i do it with Realm?

In the SQLite / MySQL, i can use `UNION` to combine the queries and `GROUP BY` to group common field's value.

Im switching to Realm and now i'm stucking in how to perform it.

Here is an example about the query in SQLite

```
SELECT w1,abc('\(word)', kd) as lscore,freq FROM ng1 WHERE kd LIKE '\(beginchar)%\(lastchar)' 
UNION 
SELECT w2,abc('\(word)', kd) as lscore,freq FROM ng2 WHERE w1='\(lastword)' AND kd LIKE '\(beginchar)%\(lastchar)' ORDER BY lscore ASC,tp DESC,freq DESC LIMIT 0,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm doesn't currently support UNION's

Comment: Really? So what am i suppose to do with it? roll back to SQLite?

Comment: @TomSawyer you can query your models and construct a new array with properties you need, then you can sort this new array.

Comment: i have to create two queries and combine the result, but it still little bit different with Union of SQLite. And so if i do the sort with `.sort({ abc(word,b: $0.w1) < abc(word,b: $1.w1) })` the speed is quite slower than SQLite 10 times